# How can I use mod_rewrite to rewrite a query string working with W3 Total Cache?

Tags: wordpress, apache, mod-rewrite

I'm using WordPress with W3 Total Cache. W3 Total Cache is set to cache requests with query strings, which is working just fine.

However, I have a couple of pages with very different queries that I still want to cache as one request, since the query string is just used by Javascript on the page to create dynamic content based on the query.

So, let's say I have the requests:

www.site.se/foo/bar/?token=78843743&baz=no

and

www.site.se/foo/bar/?token=87232310&baz=yes

At the moment, those requests are cached by W3TC separately, so the second request does not hit the cache.

How can I strip the query string using mod_rewrite so that W3TV will see them as one request and cache them as one?

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to proxy the request without the query string.

This should do the trick.  Make sure mod_proxy module is loaded and active in Apache.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/foo/bar/$ /foo/bar/? [P]
```

The bare ? at the end should clear the query string.  Just don't use the QSA flag and you should be fine.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't see how mod_proxy is applicable here? I don't really need to proxy the request, do I? I already have a working cache in PHP application.

Comment: You're proxying within apache, so the visitor sees one URL (with the query string) but PHP sees only the modified URL (without the query string).  Within Apache, it starts over with the modified URL but this is hidden from the visitor.  Although you're not using any mod_proxy commands directly, the [P] directive only works when mod_proxy module is activated.